# Is it possible to find usages of SomeMethod<T> for a specific type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper-8.0

I need to find all usages of `EditorFor<DateTime>` to undo something stupid I did.  Is it possible to find all usages of `Method<T>` for a specific `T`?

Even hack-y solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: if you use a version control system you can probably unroll changes that way. I know it's not doing it by resharper or visual studio.. But it does the job!

Answer (score 2):

If you know the type of the model, you can use Structural Search:

```
Html.EditorFor($expr$)
```

Define $expr$ as an expression placeholder and the expression type as:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<YourModelType, DateTime>>
```

And you're good to go. Unfortunately I haven't figured out a way to make the search work for less specific types -- the option `Exactly this type` only seems to cover inheritance, not variance.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to tell ReSharper to convert calls to EditorFor() to explicitly declare the generic types. Then you could do an old-fashioned text search for "EditorFor"